# Menu button is not displayed for ICS tablets but it is for Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, menu, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a problem with Menu button on Android 4.0.
Here's the interesting part of the Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>
```

The thing is that the emulator emulating a Galaxy Nexus displays the Menu button, but emulating a tablet doesn't display de Menu button.

According to [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html), it should be displayed (and it is in a Galaxy Nexus).

Anyone know why it's not displayed in a tablet? Anything I can do to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the document linked:

> The only exception is that if you set minSdkVersion to 10 or lower, set targetSdkVersion to 11, 12, or 13, and you do not use ActionBar, the system will add the legacy overflow button when running your app on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher.
>
> That exception might be a bit confusing, but it’s based on the belief that if you designed your app to support pre-Honeycomb handsets and Honeycomb tablets, it probably expects handset devices to include a Menu button (but it supports tablets that don’t have one).

So the system assumes your app is okay for a tablet because its set against Honeycomb, but not for an ICS phone.

Comment: I hadn't read carefully this "the system will add the legacy overflow button when running your app on a handset with Android 4.0 or higher."
So this only applies to phones running ICS.
Any suggestion to detect it's a honeycomb or ics tablet and display a button somewhere to display the menu?

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to show the legacy menu button on tablets. You could just use a standard `Button` on the top of your layout?

Comment: I did show a button in the layout to open the menu with openOptionsMenu() but that worked fine with ICS Phones and not ICS Tablets because the Action Bar wasn't present..
I ended up adding the Action Bar in my layout..

Answer (score 0):

Jump up the targetSdkVersion to 14